# Multiple values in SSRS paramter search in sql

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report and it has parameter @area.This parameter is a multiple value parameter.

For example,in SSRS ,@area='washington,DC','Delhi' 
and sql query is:

```
Select country from geography where area in(@mma).
```

However, I want the result to give me all countries where area contains 'washington' and'delhi'. @mma can have any number of values during runtime.I am using R2.

Comment: This question has been asked many times. You can't use an `in` statement because the parameter is one string. My favorite solution is using a custom Split function in the SQL. If you can't do that, you can use a `like` statement: `WHERE ',' + @mma + ',' like '%,' + area + ',%'`

Answer (score 0):

My preference for this is to use dynamic sql which would look something like...

```
declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Select country from geography where area in (' + @mma + ')'
execute sp_executesql @sql
```

However there are other solutions such as splitting the string in the SSRS parameter or even in sql.